# Azure Logic Apps- maximum buffer size

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using a HTTP connector to download a file using the get Request. Have set Allow chunking to On but still getting the error

"Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'."

Tested the endpoint with a HEAD request and it returns Range header as bytes which means it supports chunking but if I send the header   "Range": "bytes=0-1023" getting below exception

BadRequest. The provided workflow action input is not valid.

How do I read this file from Logic apps and write to datalake ? Is the restriction coming from connector or logic apps? How can this be accomplished ?